# ghostscript -dprinted failed

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

In my pdf file, I put a layer with property : never be printable
I use the -dPrinted to use the print options
=> but the layer is showed in the jpg

```
gs \
  -o test.jpg \
  -dPrinted \
  -dBATCH \
  -dNOPAUSE \
  -dNOSAFER \
  -sDEVICE=jpeg \
   layer_printstate_off.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-dPrinted=true|false` commandline parameters tell Ghostscript how to handle *annotation* and *image* objects in PDFs.

*Layers* are neither of these two -- they are something different. `-dPrinted` has no effect on Ghostscript's layer handling.

Does your file layer work with Acrobat (Reader) as intended by you? If not, this fact increases the probability that the file is "buggy". If yes, the bug is with Ghostscript.

Comment: Yes, with acrobat, the layer is not printed : is there a way with ghoscript to not printed a specific layer ?

Comment: No. If the file is correctly coding your *"don't print this layer"* directive, Ghostscript should by default not print the layer. It may be a bug in Ghostscript (or Acrobat is employing some special magic to gracefully handle "buggy" files, as it sometimes does...). I'd try to open a bug @ http://bugs.ghostscript.com/  (but note, they'll need your example file too).